# Customer LTV SQL Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I m trying to figure out SQL query for calculating Customer Long term value. Here is the current table tblCustomerRevenue:

| cuid | revenue | purchase-date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 302.6 | 2022-11-30 |

Goal is to get the customer order value for every date/every customer the following metrics: 1 Day total, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year purchase totals like below. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you

| cuid | Date | revenue1day | revenue1week | revenue1month | revenue1yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-01-01 | 0 | 0 | . 0 | 302.6 |
| 100 | 2023-01-02 | 0 | 0 | . 0 | 302.6 |
| 100 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 0 | . 0 | 302.6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the dates you want to be shown.
The `revenue1day` can be today or yesterday. The same for the month column.

```sql
with tbl as (
 Select 100 cuid, 302.6 revenue, date "2022-11-30"  purchase_date

),
gen as (
Select cuid,null,purchase_date
from (Select Distinct cuid from tbl),
  unnest(generate_date_array("2022-11-15","2023-01-10")) as purchase_date

)

Select *  except(revenue)
from
(
Select cuid, purchase_date,revenue,
sum(revenue) over (partition by cuid,purchase_date) as revenue_today,
sum(revenue) over (partition by cuid,date_trunc(purchase_date,month)) as revenue_thismonth,
sum(revenue) over (partition by cuid order by unix_date(purchase_date) range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as revenue_yesterday,
sum(revenue) over (partition by cuid order by unix_date(purchase_date) range between 6 preceding and 0 preceding) as revenue_last7days, # last 6 days including today
sum(revenue) over (partition by cuid order by extract(year from purchase_date)*12+extract(month from purchase_date) range between 12 preceding and 1 preceding) as revenue_previous12months,

from
(
Select * from tbl 
  where revenue is not null
union all select * from gen
)
)
where revenue is null
order by purchase_date
```